# access macro IsNull multiple variables

Tags: ms-access, macros

```
If IsNull(delivery) = True Then
```

This code is running for one variable i.e delivery.

I have check `isNull` for three variable and I want code for that.

This code is for Access Macro.

Comment: I have to check it for three variable

Answer (score 0):

Use an `And` or `Or` operator depending on the logic that you require, for example using `And` logic:

```
If IsNull(delivery) And IsNull(variable2) And IsNull(variable3) Then
    ' Do something if all three variables are null
End If
```

Alternatively, using `Or` logic:

```
If IsNull(delivery) Or IsNull(variable2) Or IsNull(variable3) Then
    ' Do something if any of the three variables are null
End If
```